# Can I install an app from an other app and then launch its intent immediately when opening it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

**Background:** I have an app which needs to use an intent from an other app. If this other app is not installed when its intent is needed, I would like to offer it for download and install.

**Question:** If the downloaded app is opened (by the user) immediately after installing it, I would need it to open the specific intent the first app needs instead of opening it as normal. See image below.

What options do I have available, is there a common pattern for this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the downloaded app is opened (by the user) immediately after installing it, I would need it to open the specific intent the first app needs instead of opening it as normal.

That is not possible, strictly speaking. There is nothing stopping the user from pressing Open, and that will behave as normal -- you cannot change this.

If you are the author of the, um, "Monkey Trampoline" app, you could work out various hacks to recognize that it is being opened after an install from, um, "Animal Olympics", so it can route its logic accordingly (use a custom sticky broadcast, have the second app use some IPC to ask the first app "yo, am I supposed to do something special?", etc.).

It is also conceivable that `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` will be broadcast before the user clicks either Done or Open (or HOME or BACK or whatever). In that case, you could listen for that broadcast, determine that, indeed, the app just installed does involve simian somersaults, and call `startActivity()`. This will be a bit jarring for the user, insofar as all of a sudden they'd be transported from the install process into this new app. And, since the precise timing of `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` is undocumented, your mileage may vary (e.g., the user could still get a chance to tap Open before the broadcast winds its way to your app).

Comment: Sorry for potential hijack here Mark, but I have similar question. I know I can start installation with market search as `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.package.name")))`. Is there a way to call on installation dialog with a package name so I can listen for potential cancel click?

Comment: @peter_budo: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: My application needs com.evernote.skitch so then in intent I can send image and start annotation. However this is failing if Skitch missing.  I use PackageManager to check if app present if not I would start above intent, but this leave space for user not installing from opened market search result. So if I could start "installation" dialog I could listen  for cancel button click. So I'm trying to find out how/where to call this dialog. Does it make sense?

Comment: @peter_budo: If I understand you correctly, what you want is not possible. As noted in this answer, use `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` to trigger running the third-party app, and design your app such that such apps are "nice to have" but not essential. After all, any given third-party app may not be available on all devices, or in all geographic areas, to which your app may be available.

Comment: Agree on 3rd-party dependency. Skitch is used just as part of prototype so not worried. I was just trying to explore some possibilities. Thank you for help. PS: Hope to meet you on Droidcon London ;)